# Old Unregistered Users

Tags: discussion, pre-migration, user-accounts, deleted-users

Why [some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7594/732) unregistered users (from the M.Y. 1.0) do not have a user page, while [others](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/208/joe-shmoe) [do](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/87/simchastorah)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1528