# Rating of Users

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, deleted-users

[User #2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/) is IsaacMoses. Why are numbers such as 1, 4, 6, and 8 missing? Perhaps IsaacMoses is the #2. Low numbers should be in high demand. **Can't users request to switch to the lower numbers to save URL space because the other users previously disactivated their accounts?** E.g., sports teams have player numbers (on jerseys) that are constantly being switched yearly when old players leave and new players join the team. I'm not saying that Talmid Chachamim are like sports players, [lehavdil](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1294/1059), but Mi.Yodeya has definitely turned the Talmud Torah into an organized quasi-enterprise just like the NFL or NBA (again, lehavdil).

Related:

- [Old Unregistered Users](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/old-unregistered-users)
- [Disappearing users and the consequences](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/disappearing-users-and-the-consequences)

Comment: Why? ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: So many down-votes, ouch! Isn't it a good question though?

Comment: @Adam [Voting works differently on Meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add to DoubleAA's answer, if we did start assigning old numbers to newer users, this would make a lot of links point to the wrong places. For example, links to a users profile would now point to a different user's profile.

Also, referral links (i.e. `http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1295/883`) would no longer give credit to the proper user, and as many of these links are posted off-site, maintaining these would be impossible.

Comment: In addition, just because a user is gone doesn't mean that that user's *data* is gone.  Internal links (in the SE database) would break too.

Comment: Best answer, because it includes both answers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Your account number is given sequentially from the start of Mi Yodeya. I was the 759th user to join. I see no reason why anyone would want to change their number, as it's meaning is essentially an indication of when you joined Mi Yodeya not the quality of your user.

Comment: Good point, that is true.